# Compiling scala file placed under resource folder and access it in test class

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I have a project setup as:

```
Project
|__src
|  |_main
|  | |_src_file_1.scala
|  | |_src_file_2.scala
|  |
|  |_resources
|    |_resource_file_1.scala
|
|__test
   |_test_file_1.scala
```

Source files inside main (`src_file_1.scala`, `src_file_2.scala`) are all compiled but resource file which is inside resources folder (`resource_file_1.scala`) is not compiled. It contains some scala code under a class which needs to be tested.

Is there a way to compile this class and access it inside `test_file_1.scala` which is a test file and tests all the other source files.

Note: I would like to have a way to read the source code, compile it inside test class using scala compiler and then use the compiled code for the testing purpose.

Comment: Best to follow the practice of putting the resource folder inside the main folder, so `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Why put a **Scala** file inside the resources folder?

Comment: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Add+an+additional+source+directory

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, there is a reason. In this project the actual scala code in src/main folder is the main code whose responsibility is to upload the scala code in src/resource folder. The scala code in resource folder will be running at the location where it was uploaded. For testing the entire code(scala code in src/main and scalal code in src/resource folder), I am trying to compile everything.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific reason why you want to have your project structure like that? There is a convention for sbt as outlined here https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Directories.html

```
src/
  main/
    resources/
       <files to include in main jar here>
    scala/
       <main Scala sources>
    java/
       <main Java sources>
  test/
    resources
       <files to include in test jar here>
    scala/
       <test Scala sources>
    java/
       <test Java sources>
```

Everything inside `scala` will be compiled.